# Cordova-android 11+ API splash screens vs splash screen plugin for previous SDK's?

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-android

The new version of cordova-android (11) which adds supports to API level 11 & 12, now has API splash screen support and the plugin is now deprecated.

My question is, do I still need the plugin if I target Android SDK 6 to 12 (for SDK 6 to 10) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You don't need the plugin. Android 12 ships with a compartibliity library to support android 11 and below. Its all handled within the  Cordova-Android version 11's SplashScreen API

Read more here: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/core/features/splashscreen/index.html#android-specific-information

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have implemented the splash screen configuration for cordova-android@11, I get the splash screen in Android 12 and above, but the app crashes for Android 11 and below, the documentation in cordova-android website doesn't provide much information about how to implement the backward compatibility. any ideas?

Comment: I saw the size being reduce, any workaround to enlarge it?

Comment: Even we see size being reduced. Did you figure out any workaround or fix for it??

Comment: I experienced what @Chriso did: working splash screen in 12, crash in <=11. The answer turned out to be using a precisely 240x240 db SVG. Android is also very picky about what SVG you use. Pixelmator output doesn't work, nor many of the online SVG converters out there. I used convertio.co to transform a png to SVG, then Android Studio's "Vector Asset" widget, resizng to 240db there. The resulting xml file gets put in your cordova /res directory, and point to that  in Config.xml with, e.g.   <preference name="AndroidWindowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon" value="res/screen/android/androidsplash.xml" />